# Azure Function manifest not found

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Quite new to Azure Functions.
Trying to deploy an Azure function hosted on linux (consumption plan), following [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/function-app-linux-consumption/main.bicep) with Python runtime.

The function app gets deployed successfully (without errors).
However, when I go to

I see this (functionname.azurewebsites.net):
[image: Error message]

When I go to DebugConsole (functionname.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream), I see error messages like:

```
2023-08-25T22:11:10.638Z INFO  - Pulling image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage2
2023-08-25T22:11:10.831Z ERROR - DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"manifest for mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest tagged by \"4-python3.6-appservice-stage2\" is not found"}
```

I have tried reading up, and came across this:[linuxfxversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#linuxfxversion).

So, now I have tried all possible combinations of linuxFxVersion

1. python|3.9
2. python|3.10
3. DOCKER|mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python
4. mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.9 ( from [here](https://mcr.microsoft.com/en-us/product/azure-functions/python/about))

but no matter what I try, I get the same error.

How come is it trying to resolve the image as *mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/python:4-python3.6-appservice-stage2* ?

These are some of my app settings:

[image: App Settings]

Any questions, and I can try to clarify.

EDIT 1:
I just saw [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/quickstarts/microsoft.web/app-service-docs-linux/main.bicep), Trying now to add it to siteConfig and deploy. Maybe that is the missing piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer is to set the linuxFxVersion while deploying in the appsettings. Setting it under siteconfig (the url in my EDIT 1 of the question didn't help

```
resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: location
  kind: functionAppKind
  identity: {
    type: functionAppType 
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identityId}': {} }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: hostingPlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'linuxFxVersion'
          value: 'python|3.9'   --THIS WORKED
        }
...othersettings
]
ftpsState: ftpsState 
minTlsVersion: minTlsVersion 
linuxFxVersion: 'python|3.9' ---THIS DID NOT WORK
}
    httpsOnly: httpsOnly 
}
```

Result
[image]